# ruby in steel error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio, erb

I right clicked the project file for my rails project and created a new ruby file.
Then i right clicked views and created a new erb file
I added a textbox and submit button and click on page (design) and it gives me this error:

> failed to locate layout file

can anyone help me pleasE?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Ruby in Steel in particular, but Rails applications have layout files in `[app root]/app/views/layouts`. In a new folder, run `rails someappname` and then `rails scaffold something` from the command line and then navigate to `someappname/app/views/layouts` to see what a layout in Rails looks like.